# Using a Context Free Grammar

Tags: parsing, boolean, context-free-grammar

I am attempting to write a simple parser for a personal project. As a starting exercise, I am trying to write code that evaluates simple boolean statements. For example, if I give the parser the following string:

`true AND (true OR false)`

It should return true.

It is my understanding that defining a context free grammar is the first step to writing a parser. Defining a context free grammar that fits my simple boolean statements is easy:

```
S => S OR S
S => S AND S
S => (S)
S => true
S => false
```

However, I do not understand the next step. How can I use this grammar to start evaluating statements? Am I totally on the wrong track?

Comment: Usual approach is to first write a lexer to tokenize the input stream and then use a PDA to parse the grammar. Useful tools for this task are (f)lex and yacc/bison.

Comment: Is there a more detailed description on this process? I don't understand how I would use a PDA with my grammar.

Answer (score 0):

A lexer definition file for your grammar (bool.l) could look like that:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
"true"   return TRUE;
"false"  return FALSE;
"OR"     return OR;
"AND"    return AND;
"("  return '(';
")"  return ')';
[ \t]    {}
\n   return 0;
.    return *yytext;
%%
```

This parses the input stream into tokens. The parser calls the lexer, which returns the next token each time. It is also possible to return tokens like NUMBER and setting a variable to the actual number read (same for string literals, identifiers etc).

The grammar definition (bool.y):

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%left  AND
%left  OR
%token TRUE FALSE LB RB
%%
start:  s       { printf("Result is: %d\n",  $1); }
s:    s OR  s   { $$ = $1 || $3; }
    | s AND s   { $$ = $1 && $3; }
    | LB s RB   { $$ = $2; }
    | TRUE      { $$ = 1;  }
    | FALSE     { $$ = 0;  }
%%
int main (void) {
    return yyparse();
}
```

The parser parses the tokens according to the grammar definition and executes the code in the brackets each time a rule matches. `$$` is the return value of the rule while `$n` is the value of the n'th token.

You can compile this with

```
yacc -d bool.y
flex bool.l
gcc -O2 y.tab.c lex.yy.c -o bool -ll -ly
```

and start it like:

```
echo false OR true | bool
```

or with `./bool` and input your terms on stdin.

Yacc builds a LALR(1) shift/reduce-parser from the definition file.

If you want to dive deeper on how yacc generates the parser, specify the `-v` option on generation, yacc will then write a description of the state machine (when to shift, when to reduce) to `y.output`.